# Android: How to get all child list from Firebase to arraylist

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

This is my structure Firebase database. I need get all order details (orderdate, ordername etc) to arraylist. But I don't know how much orders (order1, order2...) will be.

[database strukture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT0Up.png)

This is my model class:

```
public class OrderDetails {
String orderdate,ordername;

public OrderDetails() {
}

public OrderDetails(String orderdate, String ordername) {
    this.orderdate = orderdate;
    this.ordername = ordername;
}

public String getOrderdate() {
    return orderdate;
}

public void setOrderdate(String orderdate) {
    this.orderdate = orderdate;
}

public String getOrdername() {
    return ordername;
}

public void setOrdername(String ordername) {
    this.ordername = ordername;
} }
```

This is my code:

```
 ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Customers").child(cityID).child(customerID).child("orders");

List<OrderDetails> orderList = new ArrayList<>();

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for( DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        OrderDetails details = postSnapshot.getValue(OrderDetails.class);
        orderList.add(details);
        toast.makeText(getContext(), orderList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

} });
```

But this code not working. Need help please!

Comment: Why do you say it's not working? Do you have an error? How did you test it?

Comment: I add toast toast.makeText(getContext(),  orderList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); and get next date: [com.example.janedtj.shopapk.models.OrderDetails@8a15b85, com.example.janedtj.shopapk.models.OrderDetails@474adda]

Comment: Please add that line of code in your actual code.

Comment: I added this line.

Comment: If you a re using `Toast.makeText(getContext(), details.getOrdername(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`, does it toast the name of the order?

Comment: Oh, yes, in toast is name of the last order :)

Comment: When I want to get size of list listSize = orderList.size(); I get 0, but in toast I get name of order. Why list size is 0?

Comment: Just added as an answer.

Comment: Please see the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that your are passing as the second argument in your `makeText()` method a `List` object instead of a String. The following message that you get:

> [com.example.janedtj.shopapk.models.OrderDetails@8a15b85, com.example.janedtj.shopapk.models.OrderDetails@474adda]

Is in fact what `toString()` method returns. It represents the address of the `List` object from the memory. If you want to display for example, what your order name property holds, please change the following line of code:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), orderList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), details.getOrdername(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Please also note, if you want to get the size of the list, the following lines of code is required:

```
for( DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    OrderDetails details = postSnapshot.getValue(OrderDetails.class);
    orderList.add(details);
}
Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(orderList.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And should be placed outside the for loop as you can see.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Size is 0 again.

Comment: Please add to your question the entire code that you are using for that.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you so much. But when I added this line Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(orderList.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); outside addValueEventListener, size was 0. Why?

Comment: Because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774). You're welcome, cheers!

Comment: Thank you!! I use this method and it's work great but now I don't now how I can use this date outside readDate()?

Comment: This question is not related with the initial one. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Ok, thank you! :)  I created a new question.

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write it to you.